# Spyder :An error ocurred while starting the kernel

Tags: python, anaconda

The ipython console is constantly throwing this error and I tried :

- updating spyder
- Uninstalling and reinstalling anaconda
- Reading people's response on how they tried to fix it
  But still I could not fix this.

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File "C:\Users\bbachegowda\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
"__main__", mod_spec)
File "C:\Users\bbachegowda\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
exec(code, run_globals)
File "C:\Users\bbachegowda\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\spyder_kernels\console\__main__.py", line 11, in 
start.main()
File "C:\Users\bbachegowda\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\spyder_kernels\console\start.py", line 287, in main
import_spydercustomize()
File "C:\Users\bbachegowda\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\spyder_kernels\console\start.py", line 39, in import_spydercustomize
import spydercustomize
File "C:\Users\bbachegowda\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 27, in 
from IPython.core.getipython import get_ipython
File "C:\Users\bbachegowda\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\IPython\__init__.py", line 54, in 
from .core.application import Application
File "C:\Users\bbachegowda\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\IPython\core\application.py", line 23, in 
from traitlets.config.application import Application, catch_config_error
File "C:\Users\bbachegowda\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\traitlets\config\__init__.py", line 6, in 
from .application import *
File "C:\Users\bbachegowda\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\traitlets\config\application.py", line 10, in 
import json
File "C:\Users\bbachegowda\json.py", line 12
source = response.read()
^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

Comment: IPython is accidentally importing your `C:\Users\bbachegowda\json.py` file. You should 1) fix the error in that file and 2) move it somewhere else so it doesn't get imported on accident.

Comment: On the 2nd point: you should probably just rename `json.py` rather than move it somewhere and potentially face the same problem again some time down the line.

Answer (score 0):

The module name resolution is described in https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path:

> When a module named spam is imported, the interpreter first searches
>   for a built-in module with that name. If not found, it then searches
>   for a file named spam.py in a list of directories given by the
>   variable sys.path.

It looks like for some reason, the built-in module `json` is not found and that python looks into the path where `C:\Users\bbachegowda\json.py` is. So you should reinstall python to fix the built-in module `json`.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem with Spyder when installing WinPython, version: WPy64-3.7.4.1.
However previous version: WPy64-3.7.4.0 works fine.